# On probabilities of expectations

Tags: probability

**Question**

Let $X_1 , X_2, \cdots , X_n$ be independent and identically distributed with $P(X_i =1)=P(X_i=-1)=p$ and $P(X_i=0)=1-2p$ for all $i=1,2,\cdots,n$. 
Define $$ a_n=P(\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i=1), b_n=P(\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i=-1), c_n=P(\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i=0)$$

Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n,\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n,\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n$.

**My Approach**

Since $(\prod_{i=1}^n X_i=1)=1$ hence $a_n=P(\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i=1)=P(X=1)=p$ and so $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=p$.

Similarly for others. Is this approach correct?

Comment: It is more likely you will get an answer if you show you have done some work or please briefly explain what concept (s) you are having difficulty understanding.

Comment: @TonyHellmuth Updated! Sorry!

Comment: Also do you have any information to believe that the limits have a non-alternating value?

Comment: @TonyHellmuth It's a part of a multiple choice question.  Should I post the other options as well?

Comment: @TonyHellmuth I do know that $P(X*Y) \neq P(X)*P(Y)$ for independent random variables, so no confusion there!

Comment: You mean if they are dependent? And what about the combinations when $X_i$ alternates between 1 and -1? Like for example if $n=2$, then $a_n=2p^2$, right?

Comment: @TonyHellmuth Yes, I'm confused about that as well.....I can intuitively see that $P(\prod X_i =0)$ should be a lot greater than the other two, since only one $X_i$ needs to be zero for that to occur.

Comment: Great observation - that is the starting point to attack this question. Consider the case where all of them are non-zero, which help you to compute $c_n$. Next you may need to consider some odd/even issue for $a_n, b_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $1-2p$ is a probability, we can assume that $p \leq 1/2$.
If $p<1/2$, then $c_n=1-\text{Pr[No $X_i$ is zero]=}1-(2p)^n$. Thus the third limit is 1. The sum of the three quantities is 1, so the first two limits are zero.